# react router NoMatch route on dynamic routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have this structure

```js
<Route path="user"          component={Users}>
  <Route path=":userId"     component={User}>
    <Route path=":project"  component={Project}/>
    <Route path="*"         component={NotFound} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
</Route>
<Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
```

No matter how hard i try to set `<NoMatch />`, I always can get through `url` to either `user id` or `project id` that doesnt exist. This is boggling me for two days now and I'm so confused by different approaches / answers over the internet that I'm lost.

Using `react-router v3.0.2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I was completely on the wrong track before. What I meant was, the fallback is for routes that are not defined, so something like `/foo`.

`/user/55` and `user/55/project` are valid routes even if you don't have user no. 55 in your database - you can't use the fallback here.

Comment: Can't I check the `:userId` path with an array of user id's?

Comment: I guess you can check the :userId path with an array of ids, and then redirect to the notfound route if there's no match.